# If $M < M < G$ with certain conditions and a special subgroup $U < G$, then we can choose $|G / M| = p$ and $p \nmid |M|$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $U \le G$ a subgroup of odd order. Assume that $N_G(U) = TU$ with $T = \langle t \rangle$ for some involution $t \notin U$. Also assume $U^g \ne U$ implies $U^g \cap U = 1$.

> Suppose $G$ has two normal subgroups $N < M < G$, such that $G/M \cong U/(U\cap M)$ and $N \cap TU = 1$ and $M/N$ is simple. Suppose further we have a second subgroup $V \le G$ which has the same properties as $U$ (odd order, index two in its normalizer, and $V^g \ne V$ implies $V^g \cap V = 1$) that is not conjugate to $U$ and suppose $V \cap M \ne 1$ and $V^t = V$ ($t$ from $T = \langle t \rangle$ above) and that $M \ne G$.
>
> Then we can find $\hat N, \hat M$ which have the same properties as $N, M$, i.e. $\hat N < \hat M < G$, $G/\hat M \cong U/(U\cap \hat M)$ and $\hat N \cap TU = 1$ and $\hat M / \hat N$ is simple and furthermore $|G / \hat M| = p$ and $p \nmid |\hat M|$

I do not understand why we can choose $\hat N, \hat M$ in such a way? Any help would be appreciated. This is part of a proof, I know that are a lot of assumptions, but unfortunately I do not see any way to simplify it.

Comment: I don't think your question makes sense. "we can assume" is only meaningful when you are in the middle of the proof of something. It makes no sense by itself.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for your comment. I changed the question, hopefully it is clearer now. Yes, this comes from a proof, and in this proof I do not understand what going on at this step.

Comment: Where is the $p$ coming from? Some arbitrary prime dividing $|G|$?

Comment: It means there exists some prime $p$ such that the conditions holds.